# Wrong Concept in C++ Program

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following program:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;
    i=(++a[1]);
    j=a[1]++;
    m=a[i++];
    printf(" The value of i is %d\n",i);
    printf(" The value of j is %d\n",j);
    printf(" The value of m is %d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

According to my concept ,the values of i , j and k should be 2 , 2 and 15 respectively. But the compiler show the value of i , j and  as 3 ,2 ,15 respectively ? Why ? Can you explain the logic behind this output ?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Here's [a tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0).

Comment: Your link is a great resource for me . Thank you .

Comment: If it's difficult for you to see this: Just don't do several things at once. This could have been very much clear if you've written it as `++a[i]; i = a; a[1]++; j = a[1]; m = a[i]; i++;`. There's no benefit of jamming statements together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's follow what happens to `i` throughout your program:

```
int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
i=(++a[1]); // i is now 2 (a[1]+1)
m=a[i++];   // after this, i=3
```

Comment: the compiler show the value of i , j and m as 3 ,2 ,15 respectively ? Why ?

Comment: According to your question, you are already in agreement with your compiler about `j` and `k`. My answer explains `i`.

Comment: @OcenaPothik You must either forgot 1. The `++` in `(++a[1])` 2. The `++` in `m=a[i++];`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing seems to be wrong here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5]={5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;
    i=(++a[1]); //i=2; a[1] = 2; i.e first increment a[1] then equate i to a[1]
    j=a[1]++; //j = 2; a[1] = 3; i.e first equate j to a[1] then increment a[1]
    m=a[i++]; //m = a[2]=15; i=3; i.e. first equate m to a[i] then increment i
    printf(" The value of i is %d\n",i);
    printf(" The value of j is %d\n",j);
    printf(" The value of m is %d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to my concept ,the values of i , j and k should be 2 , 2 and 15 respectively. But the compiler show the value of i , j and as 3 ,2 ,15 respectively ? Why ? Can you explain the logic behind this output ?

Comment: @Ocena Pothik, with the operation ++a[1] you first increment a[1], then  equate i to a[1] which makes 2. in the third step i++ makes i 3

Answer (score 0):

in the statement`i=(++a[1]);`,first the value of a[1] is incresed by 1.Then it is assigned to i,by now i is 2.
see u do the assignment `m=a[i++]`.There is precedence here.First a[i] by which i is 2 is assigned to m,then the value of i is increased in this statement.Now i is 3.So first is the assignment,then is the increment.which is not the case if the statement is`m=a[++i]`.In this statement i is increased first then do the assignment